# get mysql resultset in ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to get multiple bus's last location from table (MAX (ID)) after every 5 seconds.

1) How to send resultset from ajax response ?

2) How to fill markers[] from ajax response ?

What i did is :

```
<script>

 function autoUpdate(){
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax/getlatlong.php',
        sync: true,
        success: function(data){

        var json = $.parseJSON(data); 
        var bus_id=json.bus_id;
        var latitude =json.latitude;
        var longitude=json.longitude;

        alert(latitude);
        alert(bus_id);

    document.getElementById("lat").value = latitude;
    document.getElementById("longi").value = longitude;
       }
       });
        // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);

}

autoUpdate();


    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
    ['Manly Beach', 28.64321, 77.11578],
    ['Manly Beach', 27.64321, 76.21578],
    ['Manly Beach', 26.64321, 77.31578],
    ['Manly Beach', 25.64321, 77.87178],
    ['Manly Beach', 24.64321, 77.71578],
    ]; 

</script>
```

**getlatlong.php**

```
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die('database error'.mysql_error());
    $db_con=mysql_select_db($db,$con);

    $q=mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM `tbl_map` where agency="1" group by bus_id")or die(mysql_error());
    while($res=mysql_fetch_array $q)){
    $id=$res['id'];
    $q1=mysql_query("select latitude,longitude,bus_id from tbl_map where id='$id'");
    $res=mysql_fetch_array($q1);
    echo json_encode($res);

    }
```

Comment: In order to use data returned from $.ajax call, you can do like this:
`var res = $.ajax({...}); var data = $.parseJSON(res.responseText);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your success function you simply have to run over your response:

```
$j.each(data, function (i, val){
        var lat = val.latitude;
        var lng = val.longitude;
        printMarker(lat, lng);
    });
```

For all markers, define an array to keep the reference of each created marker:

```
 var markers = []; //Global Marker Array
```

Then simply call a function within the $.each() where you create a marker and push it´s reference into the global array:

```
function printMarker(lat, lng){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
            icon: icon,
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
    }
```

If this is not what you expected you have to clarify your question.

EDIT: 
You are using an deprecated way to communicate with the database, in my provided example I´m using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
    try {
        $stmt = $this->dbCon->prepare("select latitude,longitude,bus_id from tbl_map where id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

        if($stmt->execute()) {
            if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
                while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    $response[] = $row;
                }
            }else{
                $response = null;
            }
             echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }catch (PDOException $e) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javasript code goes here

```
<script>

 function autoUpdate(){
   $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: 'ajax/getlatlong.php',
        sync: true,
        success: function(data){

        var resultSet = $.parseJSON(data).resultSet; // Your result set
        /*var json = $.parseJSON(data);

        var bus_id=json.bus_id;
        var latitude =json.latitude;
        var longitude=json.longitude;

        alert(latitude);
        alert(bus_id);

    document.getElementById("lat").value = latitude;
    document.getElementById("longi").value = longitude;*/
       }
       });
        // Call the autoUpdate() function every 5 seconds
setTimeout(autoUpdate, 5000);

}

autoUpdate();


    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
    ['Manly Beach', 28.64321, 77.11578],
    ['Manly Beach', 27.64321, 76.21578],
    ['Manly Beach', 26.64321, 77.31578],
    ['Manly Beach', 25.64321, 77.87178],
    ['Manly Beach', 24.64321, 77.71578],
    ]; 

</script>
```

Your php page code goes like this

```
$con=mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die('database error'.mysql_error());

$db_con=mysql_select_db($db,$con);

$q=mysql_query("SELECT max(id) FROM `tbl_map` where agency="1" group by bus_id")or die(mysql_error());
$arr=array();
while($res=mysql_fetch_array $q)){
    $id=$res['id'];
    $q1=mysql_query("select latitude,longitude,bus_id from tbl_map where id='$id'");
    $res=mysql_fetch_array($q1);
    $arr['resultSet'][]=$res;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```